# conflicting jQuery scripts- working localy but not live

Tags: jquery

I am facing problem with javascript, I think javascripts are conflicting one another.

I am using three plugin to finish my required design.

Here is three plugin name :

```
jsScrollbar
jQuery BGPOSITION
jQuery Tab
```

I cant understand, where is the main problem... It is working fine with localhost.
But, when i uploading files to web then it is not working.

Mainly scrollbar and tabs do not work together..

I am also using another js file named `jquery.tweet.js` for twitter feed.

demo site currently up here http://www.aboud-aboud.com/demo/

any advise appreciated

Comment: Does it throw any error? Which browser did you test? Did it work in the same browser locally?

Comment: Your page is returning a syntax error Unexpected end of document in Chrome dev tools...  Are you sure it works locally?  If it works in one place but not another, it likely means there is no issue with the code, but some difference between the two environments which we won't be able to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

When you uploaded it, it appears all newlines have been stripped from your HTML. In your HTML, you have some JavaScript. The JavaScript includes comments. So to the browser, it sees this:

```
<!-- some stuff... -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         // a comment which includes the entire rest of the document
```

After the first comment, it spans the rest of the line, and since the entire document has been packed on to one line, it spans the rest of the document. Therefore, it's a JavaScript syntax error, since JavaScript keeps waiting for the `});</script>` to close the script, but it never gets there, because, again, the rest of the document is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug says:

> missing } after function body

So maybe there is an error in your javascript that stops the execution. Are you sure your code is ok?